# Jquery Datepicker - disable tomorrow and if Time after 9 pm disable day after tomorrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Working on order system, and i want user to order from next day(tomorrow) and if today is after 9:00PM, user should order from next to next day(day after tomorrow), I am using Jquery Datepicker

Below is myscript with no weekends

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
   beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var today = new Date();
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
   minDate: today.getHours() >= 21 ? 2 : 1

   });
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/918/).

Comment: @Beginner, I want to check if the hour during the pm time, then disable the next day otherwise keep the next day open... any advice would be great!

Comment: @Haidar You can change the time from 9pm i.e. 21 to 12